# Can’t open Tabpy (or anything else) using cmd prompt

Tags: python, tabpy

I installed Python and added it to my Local environment path. Cmd prompt does recognize it.

I installed some packages, including TabPy and I get the same error when I try to open it in cmd prompt. I type in “TabPy” and it says ‘TabPy’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to add something else to  my local path to get this to work? I’ve tried to add the location of the file but I get the same error message.

Comment: I don't know anything about TabPy, but if it installs some executable binary, you need to add that to your PATH too! Usually modules install the binaries in the `Script` folder of your python installation (where your python.exe is located).

Comment: Thank you. You were right! I needed to add the Script folder.

Comment: The command is `tabpy`, not `TabPy`. Here is the documentation for how to install and start TabPy - https://github.com/tableau/TabPy/blob/master/docs/server-install.md